# Is there a way to remove my account from an Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, entra-id

A while ago I was added to an Azure Active Directory that was managed by someone else, but I no longer have access to any of the subscriptions or resources that belong to the AAD. Is there any way that I can remove myself from this AAD so that it no longer shows up under my account as an available directory? I am not an administrator on the AAD and do not see any way to remove myself. Perhaps I need to reach out to the administrator and see if he can remove me? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When you are added to another organization's tenant as a collaborator, you can use the "tenant switcher" in the upper right to switch between tenants. Currently, there is no way to leave the inviting organization, and Microsoft is working on providing this functionality. Until this feature is available, you can ask the inviting organization to remove you from their tenant.

See more information or details in this official document :[Azure Active Directory FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-faq)

---

## Update:

You can leave a tenant by yourself if you’ re a guest user which was invited to the tenant.

For more details about how to leave a tenant, you can refer to this [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/leave-the-organization).

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm going to mark this as the answer since there is currently no way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Seems like this is still an issue :(

Comment: This is now available: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/leave-the-organization

Comment: @benjguin  Hi, Thanks for your comment. You’re right, guest users can leave a tenant by themselves. I will update this in my answer.;-)

Comment: what about personal accounts?  the documentation only seems applicable to work accounts

Answer (score 0):

This solution also works for personal accounts.  Follow this guide: https://blog.jongallant.com/2018/09/remove-yourself-azure-subscription-tenant/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/500019)

Comment: This question popped up in the review queue for some odd reason, and the graphic heavy blog still doesn't have a simple answer. I have added it to archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/20211025182515/https://blog.jongallant.com/2018/09/remove-yourself-azure-subscription-tenant/